# How do I reverify domain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I received a notification from Firebase to reverify my custom domain. Going into the firebase hosting dashboard, I only have one button to press on[image]

Once I press it, I get the error:

```
We couldn't verify your domain . Please check your settings and try again.
```

What settings is it referring to? 
On the DNS provider side nothing changed. Still have the records as configured when I first set up firebase hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Received official word from Firebase:

> We are aware of the deep impact it might be having for your project,
> but I assure you we are working on it as our top priority. Our
> engineering team is aware of this problem and even though they are
> already working on it, the issue is still affecting several projects.
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience and will keep you updated as soon as
> more information is available.

Answer (score 3):

**[UPDATE]**
https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Hosting/21001

There is now an open ticket

Answer (score 2):

Seems that they have fixed issue.
I just pressed "Verify" button again now and status says "Connected".